# Desktop client web server communication

Tags: java, servlets, webserver, client-server, protocolexception

I am doing client server communication. I got both connected via `URLConnection` classes.

Now I am trying to send log in information to server, Server will check if information is correct else it will ask me to log in again and for this scenario lets assume log in was unsuccessful. But after getting response from server when I try again to send log in information I am getting

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Cannot write output after reading input.
```

Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL(uniRL);

java.net.URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

while(true){
    System.out.println("Enter 1-login , 2-Exit");
useroption = input.nextLine();
numOption = Integer.parseInt(useroption);
if( numOption == 1){
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
            connection.getOutputStream());
    user_login = login();
    writer.write(user_login[0]+"@");
    writer.write(user_login[1]);
    writer.flush();
    //out.close();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
    while ((tempString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        decodedString = tempString;
        //System.out.println(decodedString);
        //System.out.println(decodedString.equalsIgnoreCase("unknown user"));
    }
    in.close();
    if((decodedString.equalsIgnoreCase("unknown user"))){continue;}
    else{break;}
}
```

Comment: Which is the line where you are getting this exception ? Posting the exception trace would help.

Comment: I am getting exception when the loop goes for its second iteration. and tries to write something for second time.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `in.close()`, you're actually closing the stream used by the URL connection.  You'd need to call `url.openConnection()` again to re-open the stream...

Comment: brother thanks for help i tried it without in.close(). it is still not working. i am getting same exception....

Comment: I'm not sure why you've chosen `URLConnection` to do this, I'd probably do a straight `Socket` connection, personally

Comment: can you give me some good example/link for using socket with desktop(client) and web server? It will be really helpful..thankyou

Comment: @HaseebWali What protocol are you using?? HTTP??